# Finding the length of each string within a column of a data-frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, string-length

I wish to calculate the number of characters of every string of the `name` column. My dataframe `sample` is as shown below :

```
date        name           expenditure      type
23MAR2013   KOSH ENTRP     4000             COMPANY
23MAR2013   JOHN DOE       800              INDIVIDUAL
24MAR2013   S KHAN         300              INDIVIDUAL
24MAR2013   JASINT PVT LTD 8000             COMPANY
25MAR2013   KOSH ENTRPRISE 2000             COMPANY
25MAR2013   JOHN S DOE     220              INDIVIDUAL
25MAR2013   S KHAN         300              INDIVIDUAL
26MAR2013   S KHAN         300              INDIVIDUAL
```

Why is that `nchar` giving me a list of random numbers? So is `str_length()` from `stringr` package

```
Length <- aggregate(nchar(sample$name), by=list(sample$name), FUN=nchar)
```

Output

```
         Group.1       x
1 JASINT PVT LTD       2
2       JOHN DOE       1
3     JOHN S DOE       2
4     KOSH ENTRP       2
5 KOSH ENTRPRISE       2
6         S KHAN 1, 1, 1
```

Desired Output :

```
     Group.1       x
1 JASINT PVT LTD       14
2       JOHN DOE       8
3     JOHN S DOE       10
4     KOSH ENTRP       10
5 KOSH ENTRPRISE       14
6         S KHAN       6
```

---

The csv for the above table :

```
"Date","name","expenditure","type"
"23MAR2013","KOSH ENTRP",4000,"COMPANY"
"23MAR2013 ","JOHN DOE",800,"INDIVIDUAL"
"24MAR2013","S KHAN",300,"INDIVIDUAL"
"24MAR2013","JASINT PVT LTD",8000,"COMPANY"
"25MAR2013","KOSH ENTRPRISE",2000,"COMPANY"
"25MAR2013","JOHN S DOE",220,"INDIVIDUAL"
"25MAR2013","S KHAN",300,"INDIVIDUAL"
"26MAR2013","S KHAN",300,"INDIVIDUAL"
```

Comment: Do you need to include the `spaces` also in the count?  In the expected output, there is some inconsistency with regard to number of characters., for example, in the first row, space also was counted, but in the last row, `5` the space is omitted If it is a typo `data.frame(Group=unique(sample$name), x=nchar(unique(sample$name)))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also `apply` `nchar` to your dataframe and get the result from the corresponding column:

```
data.frame(names=temp$name,chr=apply(temp,2,nchar)[,2])
      names chr
1     KOSH ENTRP  10
2       JOHN DOE   8
3         S KHAN   6
4 JASINT PVT LTD  14
5 KOSH ENTRPRISE  14
6     JOHN S DOE  10
7         S KHAN   6
8         S KHAN   6
```

Answer (score 3):

If the last row in "Desired Output" is a typo,

```
 aggregate(name~name1, transform(sample, name1=name),
                         FUN=function(x) nchar(unique(x)))
 #            name1 name
 #1 JASINT PVT LTD   14
 #2       JOHN DOE    8
 #3     JOHN S DOE   10
 #4     KOSH ENTRP   10
 #5 KOSH ENTRPRISE   14
 #6         S KHAN    6
```

Or

```
 Un1 <- unique(sample$name)
 data.frame(Group=Un1, x=nchar(Un1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, use `data.table`

```
dtx[,PepSeqLen := nchar(PepSeq)]
```

Comment: Error message: 'nchar()' requires a character vector