# how to use R to modify the CHAR length of a column(type) to 1

Tags: r, rscript

By Referring this: [Finding the length of each string within a column of a data-frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958101/finding-the-length-of-each-string-within-a-column-of-a-data-frame-in-r). I could see the code `data.frame(names=temp$name,chr=apply(temp,2,nchar)[,2])` that says 'temp' what does temp mean here?

I'm trying to figure out how to make the CHAR length of the column 'type' in a data frame 'df1'  to 1.

Could someone help me how to accomplish this in R?

**df1**

```
date        name           expenditure      type
23MAR2013   KOSH ENTRP     4000             COMPANY
23MAR2013   JOHN DOE       800              INDIVIDUAL
24MAR2013   S KHAN         300              INDIVIDUAL
24MAR2013   JASINT PVT LTD 8000             COMPANY
25MAR2013   KOSH ENTRPRISE 2000             COMPANY
25MAR2013   JOHN S DOE     220              INDIVIDUAL
25MAR2013   S KHAN         300              INDIVIDUAL
26MAR2013   S KHAN         300              INDIVIDUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Temp here is the name to look into. Apply is basically a glorified for-loop over the margins (rows or columns) of an array of data.frame. So in this case it is applying "nchar" to each column (margin = 2) of the data.frame stored in "temp".
What you're looking for instead is `substr(df1$type, 1, 1)[[1]]` to extract the first character of each value in the `type` column.

```
df1$type <- substr(df1$type, 1, 1)
```

Comment: It appears to work, but how do I set the default length for a column 'type' to 1? Looking for your help on this.

Comment: R doesn't have "fixed length" strings by default. In SQL you could have a `CHAR(1)` but in R strings always have variable lengths. To ensure its fixed you'll have to take substring whenever you load your data into R or change data into the column.